# how to send array packet to socket

Tags: php

I want to write and read a message on socket in PHP 
My write message is =  82,10,1,6,150,249 
My read message is = 82,10,1,6,148,297 
I write this code but do not wrok. 
Tips: my message is array

```
 $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

$message = array('1'=> '82', '2'=>'10', '3'=>'1' ,'4'=>'6' ,'5'=>'150' ,'6'=>'249');
$len = strlen($message);

socket_sendto($sock, $message, $len, 0, '192.168.43.232', 5050);
socket_close($sock)
```

Comment: $message should be the string enclosed within qoutes

Comment: put $message = "82,10,1,6,150,249";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $host = "192.168.1.1";
    $port = 8080;


    //Create Packet
    $TurnOn = array(82, 10, 1, 6, 150, 249);
    foreach ($TurnOn as $chunk) {
        $message .= chr($chunk);
    }

    //Create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (!$socket) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }


    //Connect socket to remote server
    if (!socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }


    //Send the message to the server
    if (!socket_send($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0)) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    socket_close($socket);
```